# Background tasks in swift 3

Tags: swift, background-task

What is equivalent of respond to selector for background tasks? I found the code in Objective-C. I'm trying to get the same in Swift.

Here is the Objective-C code:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:)]){
    bgTaskId = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    })
```

Swift code:

```
if application.responds(to: #selector(self.beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler)) {
    bgTaskId = application.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {() -> Void in
        print("background task \(UInt(bgTaskId!)) expired")
    })
```

It's saying BackgroundTaskManager has no member 'beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler'.

What is the exact thing we can replicate in Swift 3?

Comment: try `#selector(beginBackgroundTask)`

Comment: What is the type of `application`?

Comment: let application = UIApplication.shared
application declaration is this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are attempting to support iOS 3 or earlier, there is no need to check for the existence of the selector since it was added in iOS 4.0.

But the Swift selector would be: `beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:)`.

Here's a simple trick when trying to convert an Objective-C API into Swift. Pull up the API documentation in Xcode or online. Choose the Objective-C APIs. Find the method you wish to convert. Then switch the documentation to the Swift APIs. In a case like this you will now see the same method but in Swift.